# How get my website Facebook comment in one place?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi Guys I am using Facebook comment API for my website

In this for every url , **[Facebook Comment](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/)** thread is active

Like for **id=2,id=3**

**www.mysite.com/page2.php?id=2** for this 5 comments come

**www.mysite.com/page3.php?id=3** for this 15 comments come

Now i want to show total **20 comments** on a page  **www.mysite.com/all_comments**

How will i do this.

Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

```
  This is possible only if you have your post id for which you want to get comments on that particular posts 

 //Select total no of comments on this post from facebook
    $fquery = "SELECT comment_info FROM stream WHERE post_id ='".$idd."'";
    $fparam = array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $fquery );
    $fql = $facebook->api($fparam);
    $cmcount = $fql['0']['comment_info']['comment_count'];


    /fetch comments,time,id from facebook on current post
        $fquery2 = "SELECT fromid, time,text , id  FROM comment WHERE post_id='".$idd."' LIMIT $ofset,$cmcount ";
        $fparam2 = array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $fquery2 );
        $fql2 = $facebook->api($fparam2);
```

Comment: i get according to post id but i want to get all post comment on one palace but thanks for giving your time