# How to display ALL Facebook Comments on my Blog in ONE place?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

Yes, before you ask, I need to clarify that [I looked a possible
 solution up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129406/how-get-my-website-facebook-comment-in-one-place) but that wasn't what I'm trying to achieve.

What I really wan't to do cannot be explained in a few words so I'm going to give a short verbose explaination.

- Like this familiar interface of comment-tool in [facebook's developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments) , I want to be able to see people/pages commenting on my different posts(webpages) in a single static page onmy website.(***Pictures below***):

**Image-1:** *Comment-tool interface on developers.facebook.com* [image: Comment-tool interface on developers.facebook.com]

**Image-2:** *Image of people commenting on some webpage displayed beside their name... and subsequent comments on different webpages following it*
[image: Image of people commenting on some webpage displayed beside their name... and subsequent comments on different webpages following it]

- Ofcourse, I could use the [comment-tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments) present in developers.facebook.com but that gives me access to me and my collaborators only. **I need any visitor to be able to see what people are commenting on different posts, in a single page.**
- Since, this feature is already an option for comment-tool/app admins and moderators, I stand within reason to think that there must be some way to do this publicly too!

---

### tl;dr version:

I want to bring the comment-tool interface found in developer.facebook.com to a webpage on my blog. Can anyone help me? I might drop a bounty if I really like your soultion :)

Comment: There is no built-in way to achieve this.

Comment: I figured. That's why I'm asking if somebody has found a workaround. It is obviously working in the facebook developers panel so there seems to be a way to do this. I wonder why facebook hasn't made it built-in, it could certainly be a good replacement for the activity tool that they depreciated some years ago :3